# how to read data do array structure?

Tags: c, database, types, structure, readfile

I have a structure of rooms in hotel, i want to read a data of room - code,price,status. I have a problem with reading a information about rooms from file roomdata.dat

```
typedef struct roomsInHotel
{
    char code[3];    //Code of room: available names p1,p2,p3
    float price;    
    int status;     //room is available(1) or unavailable (0)
}Hotel;

int readRoomData ()
{
    char c;
    int hotelSize = 1;
    int read = 0;
    FILE * roomReadFile = fopen("roomdata.dat", "rb");;

    if (roomReadFile == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file.\n");
    }
    
    while ((c = fgetc(roomReadFile)) != EOF) {
        if (c == "\n") {
            hotelSize++;
        }
    }
    Hotel hotelRoom [hotelSize];
    do
    {
        read = fscanf(roomReadFile, "%c,%f,%d\n", hotelRoom[0].code, &hotelRoom[0].price, &hotelRoom[0].status);

    }while (!feof (roomReadFile));
    fclose(roomReadFile);
    printf ("%d", hotelSize);
    return hotelSize;
}
```

i want to read data from .dat plik saved by my program. I dont have any compilator error. I tried to use .txt file and .dat its still not working

```
void saveRoomData (Hotel hotelRoom[], int hotelSize)
{
    FILE * roomDataFile = fopen ("roomdata.dat", "w");
    if (roomDataFile == NULL) {
        printf ("Failed to open file\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    else {
    for (int i = 0; i < hotelSize; i++) {
        fprintf (roomDataFile, "%s,%.2f,%d\n", hotelRoom[i].code, hotelRoom[i].price, hotelRoom[i].status);
       }
    }
    fclose (roomDataFile);
}
```

It's supposed to write data from file p3,900.000000,0, saved like this to a array of structure. For Example p3 to hotelRoom.code. Data in a structure are null or wrong numbers like 123121

```
int main()
{   

    int hotelSize;
    hotelSize = readRoomData();
    Hotel hotelRoom [hotelSize];
    enterRoom (hotelRoom, hotelSize);
    saveRoomData(hotelRoom, hotelSize);
    /*Input information about rooms*/
    mainMenu (hotelRoom, hotelSize);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What problem do you have? How do I believe it doesn't work? How is it supposed to work?

Comment: 1) `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. 2) You ought to exit the program if `fopen()` failed, you can't read from a `NULL` pointer. 3) `while (!feof)` is incorrect. The purpose of `feof` is not to check whether the next read will return `EOF`.

Comment: It's supposed to write data from file p3,900.000000,0, saved like this to a array of structure. For Example p3 to hotelRoom.code. Data in a structure are null or wrong numbers like 123121

Comment: ...4) `exit (0);` is equivalent to `exit (EXIT_SUCCESS)`. 5) You're missing the `main()` function. 6) You're not checking the return value of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to rewind the file as your file is at its end
2. `Hotel hotelRoom [hotelSize];` defines local variable which will not be available when function returns.
3. You use the wrong scanf format to read the string. You need to use "%2s" instead of "%c" as you pass the pointer to char.
4. `char c;` => `int c;` I advice to read the functions documentation before writing the code.
5. Always check the result of scanf (and basically all I/O functions) to check for the status.

Comment: You might add that `fscanf` only reads into ` hotelRoom[0]` for all entries in the file.